# Converting a cursor/while loop into a set based approach

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL and I am trying to update a stored procedure that has a cursor in it. I had never seen a cursor prior to this one. The cursor's select statement has an inner join, but returns only a single column of IDs. The cursor calculates the number of deleted accounts for every ID, on a row by row basis.
At the end of the stored procedure, the number of deletion variables are inserted into a table

I was hoping someone that understands more about cursors/while loops would be able to suggest the best way to convert the code above into an efficient set based approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a set based way:

```
;WITH IDS AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c.p_id 
    FROM dbo.deletion_h dh    
    INNER JOIN dbo.Child c 
        ON dh.C_id = c.c_id     
    WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(25),dh.delete_date,101) = @ReportDate 
    AND c.isT = 1    
    AND c.p_id NOT IN (SELECT p_id FROM dbo.Parent WHERE support = 'Y') 
), Data AS
(
    SELECT  p_id,
            COUNT(*) ActiveChild,
            SUM(CASE WHEN isT = 1 AND [level] <> 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) activePk8,
            SUM(CASE WHEN isT = 1 AND [level] = 'H' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) activeHS
    FROM dbo.child c
    WHERE [login] <> 'f'
    AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM IDS 
                WHERE p_id = c.p_id)
    GROUP BY p_id
)
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN ActiveChild > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumParentDeletions,
        SUM(CASE WHEN activechildPk8 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumDeletionsPk8,
        SUM(CASE WHEN activeHS > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumDeletionsHS 
FROM Data
```

You can modify the last `SELECT` to make it insert those values into your table.

Comment: @user3574076 I don't see the need to first assign them in a variable and then insert them in a table when you can just do: `INSERT INTO YourTable SELECT SUM(.......... FROM Data`

Comment: @user3574076 Apparently, you forgot to add `SUM` before the `CASE`

Comment: @user3574076 Then I'll need to see some data for this, because the logic seems to be the same as the one used in the cursor

Comment: @user3574076 I think that it would be difficult. You can post some sample data in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or at least post your whole code for the sp's to try and spot the differences